# Выборка из таблиц для ленты новостей

Tags: php, mysql

Есть несколько таблиц, с разными именами столбцов, по сути одинаковый столбец у них **date** по которому надо сортировать выборку
Дак вот, как мне вывести лену новостей для юзера? Все его подписки, комментарии, ответы на комментарии, ответы к его постам и т.д.
Побывал UNION, но там запара из-за разных имен в таблице
У кого был опыт, что делать?

```
CREATE TABLE `dis` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip`  varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `is_a` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

CREATE TABLE `quest` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip`  varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `is_a` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Comment: Через left join надо

Comment: как мешают разные имена в union'е? разное количество полей может мешать, а имена роли не играют.

Comment: Там и разные кол-во полей и разные имена

Comment: разное количество полей можно привести к бОльшему количеству с помощью констант, имена не важны. покажите пару запросов для выборок соответствующих, без какой-либо структуры что-либо советовать сложно.

Comment: структуру таблиц в студию

Comment: Все, добаыил

Comment: а в чем проблема через  union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'dis' as Source, 
      `id` as MessageId, 
      CONCAT('Ответ на вопрос ',qu.nickname,' от ',DATE_FORMAT(q.`date`,'%d.%m.%y %H:%i:%s') as Subject
      `text` as MessageText,
      `date` as MessageDate, 
      `from` as AuthorId,
      `to` as RecipientId,
      `ip`,
      `is_a`
    FROM dis d
    JOIN quest q on d.question_id=q.id
    JOIN users qu on q.`from`=qu.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'quest',
      `id`,
      'Вопрос',
      `text`,
      `date`,
      `from`,
      0,//для всех
      `ip`,
      `is_a`
    FROM quest
) t
where t.AuthorId = $currentUser
order by t.`date` desc
```

Дальше этот запрос можно join'ить с юзерами, чтоб вытянуть их ники (для AuthorId и RecipientId) ну и так далее...